# JApplet display

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, timer, japplet

I am not sure what is wrong with my program.  I think it might be a problem with threads, even though I am not creating Threads.  What I have is three different classes to implement the game Minesweeper.  One is an extended JButton class MineButton that is used for the 81 ( 9 x 9 ) buttons.  The second is a an extended Container class MineField that contains the MineButtons.  Then I have the class Minesweeper that contains the MineField object.  I have a lot of it working.  Now what I am trying to do is to have the Minewseeper class accesss static information from the MineButton class.  Here, I have no idea how I should do it.  After (I believe) the field and buttons are initialized and ready for display.  I send the Minesweeper object into an infinite loop to constantly update the information from the MineButton classes.  When I do this the Applet pops up but doesn't display its contents.  And the showStatus displays zero. Which is what it should be.
Thanks for any help.

Here is the Minesweeper class

```
    public class Minesweeper extends JApplet
    {
        MineField field;
        public void init()
        {
            field = new MineField(9,9);
            getContentPane().add(field);
            setSize(field.getSize());
        }

        public void start()
        {  
            // trying to fix my problem.  Wondering if not ready for display
            field.setNumbers();
            while(!field.initialized());


            while(true)
            {
                showStatus(MineButton.flagCount + "");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does `field = new Mine Field(9,9);` do? There is a space between Mine and Field

Comment: In my actual program it is single spaced.  It creates and sets up the UI.  The Field is a container for the MineButtons.  When I don't have the while(true) loop there it works perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The least you could do would be to add some delay between refreshing the status. The way it is now you are taking the whole CPU and, besides of busy waiting being a very bad practice, the swing thread is unable to jump in and draw your stuff.

```
while(true) {
    showStatus(MineButton.flagCount + "");

     try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Str.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

A better solution would be to set up a timer, so instead of the `while` loop:

```
int delay = 1000; //milliseconds
ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        showStatus(MineButton.flagCount + "");   // need to make sure that you can call showStatus
    }
};

new javax.swing.Timer(delay, taskPerformer).start();
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea.  It might be part of the problem, but it still isnt' working.

Comment: I just read and tried the second part of your comment.  It worked perfectly.  Can you give me an explanation why one worked and the other didn't.  And perhaps a website to read more for myself?  Thanks a lot.

Comment: I can offer you some text from the docs that might explain it. `Every applet that performs tasks after initialization (except in direct response to user actions) must override the start method. The start method starts the execution of the applet. It is good practice to return quickly from the start method. If you need to perform computationally intensive operations it might be better to start a new thread for this purpose.` Apparently you shouldn't do a lot of stuff in `start()`. The `Timer` will run in its own thread and won't disturb the main thread of the applet.

Comment: I would go through the whole tutorial to get a good grasp. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/